# Node module not working in react and electron implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I am building a simple electron app using react, i needed to use the [os.homedir](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_homedir) method to get the home directory of the user.

Here is my react component,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Os from 'os'

export default class Item extends Component {

  constructor( props ) {
    super( props )
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='item-component'>
        { Os.homedir() }
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

But seems that electron is not utilizing the os module of node js. Thus an

> Uncaught TypeError: _os2.default.homedir is not a function

error occures.

Instead of importing the `os` module i also used the `require` method with no luck.

```
let Os = require( 'os' )
```

How to use node modules in electron and react setup?

### Added Project to GitHub https://github.com/rakibtg/ElectronThisIsReact

You can clone it to test ....

Comment: Does `import { homedir } from 'os';` work (if you replace `Os.homedir()` with just `homedir()`)?

Comment: @Aurora0001 No its not working. Here is the error: **Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _os.homedir) is not a function**

Comment: Are you using Webpack? If so, could you include your configuration?

Comment: No i am not using webpack

Comment: You do use Babel though, I presume. What's the configuration for that?

Comment: Please take a loot at the package.json .. https://gist.github.com/rakibtg/51e6580de123e0042b34c8b868bba9e8

Comment: Right, thanks. What's the error message if you use `require` instead? Is it the same?

Comment: @Aurora0001 Yep, a  little different **Uncaught TypeError: os.homedir is not a function**

Comment: That seems really odd. Which version of Electron are you using?

Comment: I think it is electron 1.4.8

Comment: What happens if you `let os = require('os')` then `console.log(os)`? Could you edit the output into your question?

Comment: That logs an object, here is the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/37vKU.png

Comment: That's bizarre... For some reason, `homedir()` literally doesn't exist when you require `os`. Try using the [os-homedir polyfill](https://github.com/sindresorhus/os-homedir) and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that, i have already installed the os-homdir and it has the same kind of error...

Comment: What's the exact error when you run that?

Comment: Not as expected http://i.imgur.com/JvuyW6C.png

Comment: That doesn't look like an error - can you try just running the function now rather than logging it?

Comment: The function do nothing.. i also did this `{ homedir }`

Comment: Don't use the `{ homedir }` syntax - that isn't needed here. Does `console.log(homedir())` not log the home directory then?

Comment: That is printing a `null` in the console :/

Comment: That's weird, it seems to imply that *every way of finding the home directory failed*. Could you try `console.log(process.platform)` and `console.log(env.HOME)`?

Comment: Thanks for helping :) http://i.imgur.com/xCpNEBu.png

Comment: Right, that's interesting... The code seems to say that you are running on an undefined platform. I wonder if Electron is corrupt or something - try removing all your dependencies (including `electron-prebuilt`) and reinstall to see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Aurora0001 for your help.. i would try this next morning :)

Comment: Hello @Aurora0001, i did a fresh installation but still having the same error, i guess when get compiled it creates issues.. Btw I have uploaded the entire demo project to github, if you have time please take a look at it https://github.com/rakibtg/ElectronThisIsReact i used to use this command to run the app `npm run compile && npm start`

Answer (score 4):

I know this is like 4 months late... but if it helps now try using `let Os = window.require( 'os' )`.

In my app that i'm developing using react and electron if i did not say `window.require` I would get the same error.

Comment: Thanks! I will try

Comment: window.require is not a function how can i fix this